# Using Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter in console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

Is it correct and possible to use `Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter` in console app on C#? If yes, how to add it into the project?